# Adding values from two diffrent arrays php

Tags: php

I have got the two arrays with my code execution like shown below:

```
$one = array("IN","US","IN","JP");
$two = array("10","20","30","40");
```

In above case the sequence for each value is same. i.e. the fist value for `IN = 10.` For `US = 20`
I want to add the values for the same countries. So that for india i will have the total of 40. 
I have no idea about solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the two array and use the values from the first array as the index.

```
$one = array("IN","US","IN","JP");
$two = array("10","20","30","40");
$merge = array();

// Loop through the first array
foreach($one as $index => $value){
    // If the country has not been set before, create the index
    if(!isset($merge[$value]))
        $merge[$value] = $two[$index];
    else // Add the value if it's not the first time we 'see' this country
        $merge[$value] += $two[$index];
}
```

Now if you do `$merge['IN']`, it would give you `40`.

Result of var_dump:

```
array(3) { 
    ["IN"]=> int(40) 
    ["US"]=> string(2) "20"
    ["JP"]=> string(2) "40" 
}
```